# How do I create a NGRX selector that combines data from two different feature modules?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I want to do this:

```js
export const selectPlacesForCurrentCustomer = createSelector(
   selectAllPlaces,
   selectedCustomerId,
   (places: Place, customer_id: string) => places.filter((place) => place.customer === customer_id)
)
```

However when I do this, I get this error:

> Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<State, string,
> DefaultProjectorFn>' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Selector<State, string>'.

Here is a simplified version of my application that reproduces the issue.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-ngrx-issue?file=src/app/reducers/index.ts

Here's a screenshot of my state. I want to combine these two things:
[image]

**************** Background ******************

I have two separate feature stores. Each store uses [NGRX/Entity](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity).

1. Places
2. Customer

I would like to create a selector that pulls data from both. Here's a simplified interface for both models:

```js
export interface Place {
_id: string;
customer: string;
...
}

export interface Customer {
_id: string;
}
```

Customer Module

The Customer Feature has multiple stores. I import this feature into my customer module like so:

```
 StoreModule.forFeature(fromCustomer.customersFeatureKey, fromCustomer.reducers)
```

The customer feature state looks like this:

```js
export interface CustomerState {
    [fromCustomers.customerFeatureKey]: fromCustomers.State; //I'm want pull data from here!!
    [fromPaymentMethods.paymentmethodFeatureKey]: fromPaymentMethods.State;
    [fromInvoices.invoiceFeatureKey]: fromInvoices.State;
    [fromSubscriptions.subscriptionFeatureKey]: fromSubscriptions.State;
}

// This is what I pass to the `forFeature` method in my customer module. 
export function reducers(state: CustomerState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return combineReducers({
    [fromCustomers.customerFeatureKey]: fromCustomers.reducer,
    [fromPaymentMethods.paymentmethodFeatureKey]: fromPaymentMethods.reducer,
    [fromInvoices.invoiceFeatureKey]: fromInvoices.reducer,
    [fromSubscriptions.subscriptionFeatureKey]: fromSubscriptions.reducer
  })(state, action);
}
```

If we examine the `fromCustomers.State` state, this is what that looks like:

```js
export interface State extends EntityState<Customer> {
  selectedCustomerId: string | null; // --> This is the first piece of data I'm trying to select.
  loaded: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  processing: boolean;
}
 
export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Customer> = createEntityAdapter<Customer>({
    selectId: customer => customer._id,
    sortComparer: false
});
 
export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({
    selectedCustomerId: null,
    loaded: false,
    loading: false,
    processing: false
});

...
```

As we can see above, this were I finally setup the EntityAdapter. **The important piece of data that I'm trying to select from this feature is:** `selectedCustomerId`.

I have a selector in this feature that looks like this:

```js
export const selectedCustomerId = createSelector(
    selectCustomersEntitiesState,
    (state) => state.selectedCustomerId
)
```

Place Module

Now that we have customer module summarized, let's move on to the **Place Feature.**

Similar to the customer module, I'm importing this into the place module file.

This is what my Place State looks like:

```js
export interface PlaceState {
    [fromPlaces.placeFeatureKey]: fromPlaces.State;
    //[fromSearch.searchFeatureKey]: fromSearch.State; // This is where you should add search for assignments
}

export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
  [placesFeatureKey]: PlaceState;
}

// This is what I pass to the `forFeature` method in my place module. 
export function reducers(state: PlaceState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return combineReducers({
    [fromPlaces.placeFeatureKey]: fromPlaces.reducer,
  })(state, action);
}
```

If we dive down into the `[fromPlaces.placeFeatureKey]` you'll see where I'm setting up the EntityAdapter for the place model.

```js
export interface State extends EntityState<Place> {
  selectedPlaceId: string | null;
  loaded: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  processing: boolean;
}
 
export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Place> = createEntityAdapter<Place>({
    selectId: place => place._id,
    sortComparer: false
});
 
export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({
    selectedPlaceId: null,
    loaded: false,
    loading: false,
    processing: false
});
```

I have a selector for all places:

```js
export const {
  selectIds: selectPlaceIds,
  selectEntities: selectPlaceEntities,
  selectAll: selectAllPlaces, // --> This second thing I'm trying to select. 
  selectTotal: selectTotalPlaces,
} = fromPlaces.adapter.getSelectors(selectPlacesEntitiesState);
```

The selector from place feature that I'm interested in is `selectAllPlaces`.

I hope you're still with me. **Now that I've set up the background, I would like to explain what I what hope to do, but can't figure out how.

********** *I want to do this:* **********

```js
export const selectPlacesForCurrentCustomer = createSelector(
   selectAllPlaces,
   selectedCustomerId,
   (places: Place, customer_id: string) => places.filter((place) => place.customer === customer_id)
)
```

However when I do this, I get this error:

> Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<State, string,
> DefaultProjectorFn>' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Selector<State, string>'.

Comment: Please share where you have definced `selectAllPlaces`. If possible can you reproduce the error? I am unable to reproduce if, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pdxkhk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Freducers%2Fplaces%2Fplace.reducer.ts

Comment: @OwenKelvin I have included a stackblitz that recreates the issue.

Comment: added typescript tag as issue is related to type mismatch in TS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem Debugging

Lets try to debug this code where the error is being thrown

```typescript
export const selectPlacesForCurrentCustomer = createSelector(
  selectAllPlaces,
  selectedCustomerId,
  (customer_id: string, places: Place[]) =>
    places.filter(place => place.customer === customer_id)
);
```

Below is a screenshot of IDE indicating the error is thrown in the line `selectedCustomerId`

[image: Initial Error]

In the error we also notice below line

> Property '[customersFeatureKey]' is missing in type 'import("/~/src/app/place/reducers/index").State' but required in type 'import("/~/src/app/customer/reducers/index").State'.

Now lets try to Invert the parameters

```
export const selectPlacesForCurrentCustomer = createSelector(
  selectedCustomerId,
  selectAllPlaces,
  (places: Place[], customer_id: string) =>
    places.filter(place => place.customer === customer_id)
);
```

Now we see the error is no longer on `selectedCustomerId` but now on `selectAllPlaces` and the error has changed

```
Property '[placesFeatureKey]' is missing in type 'import("/~/src/app/customer/reducers/index").State' but required in type 'import("/~/src/app/place/reducers/index").State'.
```

[image: Inverted Parameters]

### Explanation

Below is the definition of `createSelector()`

```typescript
createSelector(selectors: [Selector<State, S1>, Selector<State, S2>], projector: (s1: S1, s2: S2) => Result): MemoizedSelector<State, Result>
```

Notice something, State `Selector<State, S1>` and `Selector<State, S2>` have **The same `State`**

Below is an extract from the docs to explain why this error is being thrown

> The `createSelector` can be used to select some data from the state based on several **slices of the same state**.

Take note of the line **several slices of the same state**.

So in your case you are passing two different `State`, `State` from `places` that has a '[placesFeatureKey]' and `State` from `customers` which has a '[customersFeatureKey]' which are incompatible

### Solution

#### Option 1 - Typecast to the same type `State`

```typescript
export const selectPlacesForCurrentCustomer = createSelector(
  selectAllPlaces as MemoizedSelector<State, Place[]>,
  selectedCustomerId as MemoizedSelector<State, string>,
  (places: Place[], customer_id: string) =>
    places?.filter(place => place.customer === customer_id)
);
```

[See sample demo of this solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-ngrx-issue-p9lstt)

#### Option 2 - Instead of creating a selector use piping in the observable stream

You can simply employ piping to combine the two Streams in the component or a service

```typescript
  allPlaces$ = this.store.select(selectAllPlaces);
  selectedCustomerId$ = this.store.select(selectedCustomerId);
  selectPlacesForCurrentCustomer$ = combineLatest([
    this.allPlaces$,
    this.selectedCustomerId$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([places, customer_id]) =>
      places.filter(place => place.customer === customer_id)
    )
  );
```

[See sample demo of this solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-ngrx-issue-3lykog)

#### Option 3 - Create a selector that Selects the whole state and extract the relevant function

```typescript
export const selectPlacesForCurrentCustomer = (state: State) => {
  const places = selectAllPlaces(state as any);
  const customerId = selectedCustomerId(state as any);
  return places.filter(place => place.customer === customerId);
};
```

[See sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-ngrx-issue-ekjdvj?)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I will think through this more tomorrow before I award. Follow up question on solution 1 --> Will this solution take advantage of memoization still? I would imagine so since we're just casting the state.

Comment: @calbear47 I believe it will, though to be certain I have changed the solution to Typecast the values to `MemoizedSelector` instead.